# I want to use my s21 to download Ubuntu for my computer

Tags: boot, dell, laptop, samsung

I have a Dell latitude that is missing the OS and I was wondering if I could get Ubuntu on my cell phone and transfer the program to my computer.

Comment: You can download Ubuntu ISOs on probably any device connected to the internet, and then write to media the machine you wish to install on can boot from (*be it USB flash-media, DVD, cartridge, even magnetic tape if the device will boot from it*), but it's far easier downloading & writing media using a PC (*instructions are available for those using Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux, windows or macOS*)

Comment: Please follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you encounter problems, reference the tutorial when asking. We expect that you will search/research before asking and share your research and attempts with us when you ask. See: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask